# Spam upvoting, just wanted to let mods know

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

While I haven't been active, whenever I click on one of the Stack Exchange sites I can't help but look at my rep changes.

Anyway this is what I found. I thought I should point out that it seems strange to get 4 upvotes like this.

[image: Lots of upvoting]

Thanks for all your work!

Answer (score 4):

About the voting, I wouldn't worry about it too much. Stack Exchange has "serial voting" detection scripts to handle most of that.

Speaking of which, a lot of recently new questions and answers have been getting more than the usual votes lately, and I do see a few users on the votes pages - these guys haven't really participated much on the site. But hey, people are finding the site :)

We can't see votes, except our own, so... :)